# Order pandas barplot alphabetically ignoring upper and lower case

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a barplot from pandas.value_counts

```
 df[variable].value_counts(dropna=False, sort=False).sort_index(ascending=True).plot(kind='barh')
```

However this sorting takes into account whether the categories are upper and lower case:

i.e.

This list: `[Plant, Animal, bacteria]`

becomes: `[Animal, Plant, bacteria]`

instead of: `[Animal, bacteria, Plant]`

Is there a way of ignoring upper and lower case when ordering without changing the format in the plot? I still want to keep bacteria lower case.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Index.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.argsort.html) of lowercase index values by [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) for order and reorder by [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'variable':['Plant','Animal','Animal','bacteria','bacteria', np.nan]})
s = df['variable'].value_counts(dropna=False, sort=False)
print (s)
NaN         1
Plant       1
bacteria    2
Animal      2
Name: variable, dtype: int64

s = s.iloc[s.index.str.lower().fillna('').argsort()]
print (s)
NaN         1
Animal      2
bacteria    2
Plant       1
Name: variable, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Not really sure how to use this, should I set s =  df[variable].value_counts(dropna=False, sort=False).sort_index(ascending=True)?

Comment: This gives an error: line 4688, in argsort
    return result.argsort(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: @Agustin - I think there are missing values, do you need remove it? Or count? Answer was edited.